# YouTube API goes blank in fullscreen mode - Android

Tags: android, video, youtube, landscape, android-fullscreen

I am using the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) and have the thumbnail videos for a `List` working nicely, and when you click a video in the list, it pops open a video box over the list that plays the video. This part works. But the video box was created as part of the `API` library (I'm assuming) and so its fullscreen button in the box itself is clicked to get it into fullscreen. However, when I go to fullscreen, the video disappears and it is blank. No crash or anything, just blank. My initialization works fine. I get the `errorReason` value of `SUCCESS` when I log it. So I don't know what else could be causing this blank.

In some other `YouTube API` code I find online, they use an `Intent` to go into fullscreen mode, but this is not what the video list class from the `YouTube` sample uses, so I don't know if that's needed somehow or not. The `YouTube` sample works perfectly as a list, it shows the video list and then seamlessly goes into fullscreen (landscape) mode when you click that tiny expand button on the video box.

[image: Video box over list items]

Does it seem like I am missing anything? Keep in mind, the video box and the fullscreen mode are both fragments, and are created programmatically, not in the `UI`. In my xml, you will just see fragment placeholders with a reference to the class where their `UI` is created.

Thanks for your help.

**VideosActivity.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutelinks.cutevideos;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;


public class VideosActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnFullscreenListener {

    /** The duration of the animation sliding up the video in portrait. */
    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 300;
    /** The padding between the video list and the video in landscape orientation. */
    private static final int LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP = 5;
    protected static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    /** The padding between the video list and the video in landscape orientation. */
    private VideoListFragment listFragment;
    private VideoFragment videoFragment;
    private View videoBox;
    private View closeButton;
    private boolean isFullscreen;
    private boolean isPortrait;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        listFragment = (VideoListFragment) getFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
        videoFragment = (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById
                        (R.id.video_fragment_container);

        videoBox = findViewById(R.id.video_box);
        closeButton = findViewById(R.id.close_button);

        videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        layout();

        checkYouTubeApi();

    }

    private void checkYouTubeApi() {
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason =
                YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(this);
        Log.e("ERROR RESULT", "Error initialization result is " + errorReason);
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else if (errorReason != YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS){
            String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player),
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Recreate the activity if user performed a recovery action
            recreate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        layout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;

        layout();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the layout programatically for the three different states. Portrait, landscape or
     * fullscreen+landscape. This has to be done programmatically because we handle the orientation
     * changes ourselves in order to get fluent fullscreen transitions, so the xml layout resources
     * do not get reloaded.
     */
    private void layout() {
        isPortrait =
                getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        listFragment.getView().setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
        closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        if (isFullscreen) {
            videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START);
        } else if (isPortrait) {
            setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
        } else {
            videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
            int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
            setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
            int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4 - dpToPx(LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP);
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        }
    }

    public void onClickClose(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View view) {
        listFragment.getListView().clearChoices();
        listFragment.getListView().requestLayout();
        videoFragment.pause();
        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = videoBox.animate()
                .translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight())
                .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
        runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void runOnAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Runnable runnable) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            animator.withEndAction(runnable);
        } else {
            animator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    runnable.run();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment that shows a static list of videos.
     */
    public static class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment{
        private static final List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
        static {
            List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Corgi Puppy Cam", "kvxJNEl6OD4"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Husky Puppy Cam", "wo04ZWLAnvo"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Yorkie Puppy Cam", "Fen9ZXNS2Ug"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Schnauzer Puppy Live Cam", "i2-MnWWoL6M"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Relaxing Bird Feeder", "jMbtQLQoWZ8"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Guy Gets Smothered by Bunnies on Japan's Rabbit Island!", "pY-GncsZ-UE"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("キツネ100匹！ - Fox Village", "tMo9FWwKoiA"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Cute Alpacas!", "bwL7xUC6LqQ"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Cute Pygmy Goats!", "ScCa7fZ-xPA"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Cute Peruvian Hairless Dogs!", "le8yAr7PlSE"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Cute Baby Boar Piglets!", "Ww9zBgvxt80"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("The Red Pandas of Darjeeling District, India.", "Cn3tk-rUl5Q"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Smart and Clever Animals", "V7BVUjB93ew"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Animal Odd Couples 1of2", "k9pzi8W8At0"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Pets Interrupting Yoga", "QQYK5vT9TBI"));
            list.add(new VideoEntry("Two Chinchillas, One Sock!", "e56I_syIMwk"));
            VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }

        private PageAdapter adapter;
        private View videoBox;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity(), VIDEO_LIST);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            videoBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_box);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            String videoId = VIDEO_LIST.get(position).videoId;

            VideoFragment videoFragment =
                    (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
            videoFragment.setVideoId(videoId);

            // The videoBox is INVISIBLE if no video was previously selected, so we need to show it now.
            if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    // Initially translate off the screen so that it can be animated in from below.
                    videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
                }
                videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // If the fragment is off the screen, we animate it in.
            if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0) {
                videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();

            adapter.releaseLoaders();
        }

        public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
            adapter.setLabelVisibility(visible);
        }

    }


    private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
        private final List<View> entryViews;
        private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

        private boolean labelsVisible;

        public PageAdapter(Context context, List<VideoEntry> entries) {
            this.entries = entries;

            entryViews = new ArrayList<>();
            thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<>();
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

            labelsVisible = true;
        }

        public void releaseLoaders() {
            for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
                loader.release();
            }
        }

        public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
            labelsVisible = visible;
            for (View view : entryViews) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return entries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public VideoEntry getItem(int position) {
            return entries.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

            // There are three cases here
            if (view == null) {
                // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_tube_row_item, parent, false);
                YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
                thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
            } else {
                YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
                if (loader == null) {
                    // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
                    //    current videoId in the tag.
                    thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
                } else {
                    // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
                    //    on the loader.
                    thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
                    loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
                }
            }
            TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
            label.setText(entry.text);
            label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            return view;
        }

        private final class ThumbnailListener implements
                YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
                YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(
                    YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
                loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
                thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
                String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
                loader.setVideo(videoId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(
                    YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
            }
        }

    }


    public static class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
            implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

        YouTubePlayer player;
        private String videoId;

        public static VideoFragment newInstance() {
            return new VideoFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
            newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (player != null) {
                player.release();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
            if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
                this.videoId = videoId;
                if (player != null) {
                    player.cueVideo(videoId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            if (player != null) {
                player.pause();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                                      YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
            this.player = player;
            player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.
                    FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            player.setOnFullscreenListener((VideosActivity) getActivity());
            if (!restored && videoId != null) {
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            this.player = null;
        }
    }

    private static final class VideoEntry {
        private final String text;
        private final String videoId;

        public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
            this.text = text;
            this.videoId = videoId;
        }
    }

    // Utility methods for layouting.

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSizeAndGravity(View view, int width, int height, int gravity) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }


//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_webcams, menu);
//        return true;
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteFragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_videos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2198bb">

        <fragment
            class="org.azurespot.cutelinks.cutevideos.VideosActivity$VideoListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/close_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
                android:onClick="onClickClose"/>

            <fragment
                class="org.azurespot.cutelinks.cutevideos.VideosActivity$VideoFragment"
                android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the flag that was in the `onInitializationSuccess()` method. The flag that the YouTube sample came with was `FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT`, which according to the [YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) it actually disables the fullscreen view so that you can manually code the view. Since this flag worked in the sample from `YouTube`, I did not know I had to manually change it. So all it took was for me to change the flag, I chose `FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE`, and now going into fullscreen mode from the video box (shown above) it went into fullscreen mode and continued playing the video. Well, actually it's coded to pause, when you change orientation, but you can press play and it works.